# Is there a management service for Amazon EC2 that adds robust user security?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I know there are tools to manage your EC2 environment. I currently use the Eclipse Plugin and the iPhone app iAWSManager. What i'm looking for is a management service that allows you to create multiple users with roles and privileges. I have clients that sign up for EC2 but need help setting up and managing everything. At the very least they should be able to setup multiple logins so they can monitor who is doing what on the account (rather than sharing the single login). Better would be to assign privileges for who could  create and launch an instance, create and assign/just assign Elastic IPs/EBS to instances etc.

Since enterprises are supposed to be using EC2 how do they manage this well? How do they create audit trails of activity?

Answer (score 1):

RightScale, YLastic or EnStratus support roles and priviledges. However, they are not for free...

Comment: Are there any limits to what you can do with those tools (ex. allocate new IPs, EBS etc..) I'm looking to give full access to EC2 administration but on a named user basis so you can have multiple logins.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add [Scalr](http://scalr.net) to the list, which is a cloud management software like RightScale (disclaimer: I work there). We released our permissions feature last January. It allows you to create different teams and environments and attribute them privileges on a granular basis. It means you can grant different permissions to different people. You can learn more on this [blogpost](http://scalr.net/blog/announcements/please-sir-may-i-have-some-more/).

Scalr is available as a hosted service which includes support. If you are looking for a free solution, you can download the source code, which is released under the Apache 2 license, and install it your self.

As mentioned earlier, RightScale and enStratus are two other alternatives.